# My website scrolls to the right on mobile devices only, however there is only white space

Tags: css, mobile, sass, bootstrap-4, visual-web-developer

I have designed my own website using HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4 and SCSS with some small bits of JavaScript and JQuery. The website looks fine on the desktop but on mobile devices there is excess white space to the right, despite me setting overflow to hidden on all device sizes.

I have used developer tools to inspect all of the elements and can see no reason for this behaviour, however I feel it is something to do with the carousel, as it also happens on another site I have built only on the page with the carousel.

This can be seen at https://www.mediumcarlie.co.uk

I have used developer tools to try to inspect the issue, I have googled everything, I have set max-width to 100% on nearly all elements where I am able to, I have used media queries and Bootstrap variables to adjust the size of the carousel elements.

```
 <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
 <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
```

I expect for there to be no additional white space on smaller devices. Currently there is whitespace on the right hand side of mobile screens only on the index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

divs with class "row" in the Bootstrap should be wrapped with div with class "container". 
In your case, you have a problem in the section with id = "home-heading". Use the wrapping as below

```html
<section id="home-heading" class="py-5">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think this may be the reason! Thank you so much. Will upload it now and check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margin-right: 15px; on the #home-heading > overlay-container > row

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to do this is by adding `overflow-x:hidden;` to the HTML element since there are no contents that appear on the overflowing section by adding this you will not recieve the horizontal scroll.

Next is the reason why you are getting this:
In the home heading section there is a row present without the container class you need to add the  container class before the row in order to sort it out.

```html
<section id="home-heading">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">Loprem Ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```